# Co-related branch predictor

Tags: cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

This question is taken from *Modern Processor Design* by Shen and Lipasti.

> Consider the following code segment within a loop body for problems 5:
>
> ```
>    if (x is even) then                                (branch b1) 
>            increment a                                 (b1 taken)
>     if (x is a multiple of 10) then                    (branch b2) 
>            increment b                                 (b2 taken)
> ```
>
> Assume that the following list of 9 values of x is to be processed by 9 iterations of this loop.  8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 20, 29, 30, 31. Note: assume that predictor entries are updated by each dynamic branch before the next dynamic branch accesses the predictor (i.e., there is no update delay).
>
> Assume a two-level branch prediction scheme is used. In addition to the one-bit predictor, a one bit global register (g) is used. Register g stores the direction of the last branch executed (which may not be the same branch as the branch currently being predicted) and is used to index into two separate one-bit branch history tables (BHTs) as shown below.
>
> Depending on the value of g, one of the two BHTs is selected and used to do the normal one-bit prediction. Again, fill in the predicted and actual branch directions of b1 and b2 for nine iterations of the loop. Assume the initial value of g = 0, i.e., NT. For each prediction, depending on the current value of g, only one of the two BHTs is accessed and updated. Hence, some of the entries below should be empty.
>
> Note: assume that predictor entries are updated by each dynamic branch before the next dynamic branch accesses the predictor (i.e. there is no update delay).
>
> ```
>               8     9   10    11    12    20    29    30    31
> ```
>
> For g=0
>
> b1 predicted :  __ N____ T____N___ **_ __ T____ T_** __ __  T ______
>
> b1 actual      :__ T____ N____T____ N____ T____ T____ N____ T____ N__
>
> b2 predicted:  ____  __  N______ __ N____ __ **_ _ __ N____ __ __ N**
>
> b2 actual      :__ N____ N____T____ N____ N____ T____ N____ T____ N__
>
> For g=1
>
> b1 predicted:  ____  ____ ____ __   N______ _ **_ __  N_** **_ __ N**
>
> b1 actual      :__ T____N____ T____ N____ T____ T____ N____ T____ N__
>
> b2 predicted:  __ N______ __  N______ __  T____ N____ __ __ T____ __
>
> b2 actual      :__ N____N____ T____ N____N____  T____ N____ T____ N__
>
> [image]

What is the logic behind these table values for both g=0 and g=1?

Comment: Why does this seem like homework?

Comment: I'm still looking for the code segment for consideration. And what do you mean by "what is the logic" - how is it implemented logically, or what is the reasoning behind this algorithm?